# Is there a type for 16 size data?

Tags: c++, variables, types, size

I heard that in 32bit computer(1990~2000?) had to use a 8 size data like below;
(that I heard of... there was no 8 size type, then... )
they used like this;

```
// 8 size 
typedef union _LARGE_INTEGER {
    struct {
        DWORD LowPart;
        LONG HighPart;
    } DUMMYSTRUCTNAME;
    struct {
        DWORD LowPart;
        LONG HighPart;
    } u;
    LONGLONG QuadPart; // I'm not sure of this part;
} LARGE_INTEGER;
```

So I want to try to make a 16 size type for my own
it is ok to use it like this??

```
// 16 size 
typedef union INTERGER128 {
    struct {
        LONGLONG LowPart;
        LONGLONG HighPart;
    } u;
} _INTERGER128;
```

Comment: I know _LARGE_INTEGER exist, but I didn't know _INTEGER128 EXISTED.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used another way to may a 16 size variable

```
__declspec(align(16)) struct aa {
    long long a;
    long long b;
    char c;
}
```

this way you can make a 16 size padding in structs

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a type for 16 size data?

There are no standard fundamental types that are guaranteed to be 16 bytes. In some language implementations, there is a 128 bit integer type as a language extension.

> ```
> typedef union INTERGER128 {
>     LONGLONG LowPart;
>     LONGLONG HighPart;
> } _INTERGER128;
> ```

I see no case where your suggested union would be useful. Furthermore, the size of that union would be same as `LONGLONG`. You haven't shown how that is defined but if it is `long long` then on most systems that is a 64 bit type; not 128.

You can define a custom 128 bit class like this:

```
struct INTERGER128 {
    std::uint64_t low;
    std::uint64_t high;
};
```

---

P.S. `_INTERGER128` and `_LARGE_INTEGER` identifiers are reserved to the language implementation. You should use another name. Or just don't define a pointless alias.

P.P.S. There is a proposal for standard library based wide integers: [p0539](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/p0539r5.pdf)

Comment: thank you I changed the type to struct ( union -> struct )